# Fastest way to Group a large number of Elements in C++

Tags: c++, algorithm, c++11, optimization

I need a way to quickly group a large number of connections, currently 300k, into groups where each group has a max number of elements allowed, currently 14k, and all of the connections in the same group cannot be connected to the same point. Basically, each connection is between two points and I need them grouped into buckets where the connections in a bucket don't share a point. Hopefully that makes sense.

Here's what I have so far, which works but is rather slow:

```
for (size_t i = 0; i < ConnectionGroups.size(); i++)
{
    auto& group = ConnectionGroups[i];
    if (group.size() < MaxConnectionGroupSize) // Has room for us...
    {
        int validGroupIdx = i;
        for (size_t gIdx = 0; gIdx < group.size(); gIdx++)
        {
            const auto groupConnection = ConnectionsQuickAccess[group[gIdx]];

            // Are we directly connected to one of the Connections in this group by one degree...
            if (Connection.Point1 == groupConnection->Point1 || Connection.Point1 == groupConnection->Point2 ||
                Connection.Point2 == groupConnection->Point1 || Connection.Point2 == groupConnection->Point2)
            {
                validGroupIdx = -1;
                break; // We are, check the next group
            }
        }

        if (validGroupIdx != -1)
        {
            ConnectionGroups[i].push_back(Connection.Slot);
            Connection.Group = i;
            return;
        }
        else
            continue;
    }
}

// All groups are full, create a new group
vector<int> newGroup;
newGroup.push_back(Connection.Slot);
ConnectionGroups.push_back(newGroup);
```

This code takes 29.68s to go through 300k connections, is there a faster way of doing this? Or maybe a different approach to this?

Thank you!

Comment: What type of `ConnectionGroups`, `Connection`. What is `ConnectionQuickAccess`?

Comment: `ConnectionGroups` is a `vector<vector<int>>` the `int`'s refer to indecis in `ConnectionQuickAccess`, `Connection` simply holds 2 pointers to the points it connects and other data such as it's group index and `ConnectionQuickAccess` is a `vector<Connection*>` acts as a fast way to access all created Connections. The actual Connection objects are managed elsewhere.

Comment: I think that if you had instead of `vector<Connection*>` a container(s) which hold the data sorted like `set` or `map` according to `Point1` and/or `Point2`, the search would take 4*log(n) instead of 4*n and the whole algorithm would be n*log(n) instead of n^2.

Comment: ... or even `unordered_map` or `undordered_set` of C++11 which has O(1) complexity of searching in it...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems the code posted processes one connection, i.e., it is called `n` times where `n` is the number of connections. The algorithm is clearly `O(n * n)`: the time it takes to add new connections grows quadratic - something you generally don't want.

Unless memory is the primary constraints, I'd simple store for each group a hash containing all existing end-points and check against that, i.e., something along the lines of

```
for (std:size_t i(0); i != ConnectionGroups.size(); ++i) {
    if (ConnectionGroups[i].size () < MaxConnectionGroupSize)
        && !ConnectionGroups[i].usesEndPoint(Connection.Point1)
        && !ConnectionGroups[i].usesEndPoint(Connection.Point2)) {
        ConnectionGroups[i].addEndPoint(Connection.Point1);
        ConnectionGroups[i].addEndPoint(Connection.Point2);
        ConnectionGroups[i].addConnection(Connection);
    }
}
```

Obviously, `ConnectionGroups[i]` would be a combination of connections and a hash of end-points accessed with the corresponding functions.

Comment: Could you elaborate on the "hash containing all existing end-points" bit? How would you recommend it be implemented?

Comment: @NIZGTR: since mere existence of the key is relevant, a `std::unordered_set<EndPoint>` would do the trick. If the uniqueness of an endpoint is used to some benefit it is likely that you actually might want to associate information with the end point, i.e., you'd use `std::unordered_map<EndPoint, Information>` with whatever information is convenient.